# "Einweisung in __ betriebliche Abläufe(n)" – Akkusativ oder Dativ verwenden?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Muss ich im folgenden Satz Akkusativ oder Dativ verwenden?

**PART_A**

> Einweisung **in die** betrieblichen Abläufe in ein(em) Ingenieurbüro

*oder*

> Einweisung **in den** betrieblichen Abläufe**n** in ein(em) Ingenieurbüro

**PART_B**

> Einweisung in die/den betrieblichen Abläufe/Abläufen in **ein** Ingenieurbüro

*oder*

> Einweisung in die/den betrieblichen Abläufe/Abläufen in ein**em** Ingenieurbüro

---

Mit welchem Grammatikregeln kann das erklärt werden, sodass ich ein fundiertes Verständnis über diesen Fall habe?

Comment: A1/B2 bedeutet ?

Comment: Ein Phänomen ist das mit Sicherheit nicht. Der Sonnenuntergang ist ein Phänomen, die Wahl zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ wird in Regeln zusammengefasst.

Comment: Richtig ist übrigens PART_C: "Einweisung in die betrieblichen Abläufe eines/des Ingenierbüros"

Comment: @Stephie: A1 ist weniger falsch als A2, aber wegen "in ein Ingenierbüro" trotzdem nicht richtig - oder steh ich grad auf der Leitung?

Comment: @Em1 _Auch_ richtig, ja. Aber was hättest Du gegen die Akkusativvariante von B2 einzuwenden?

Comment: @Stephie Hm, vielleicht. Dann wäre es aber besser, in A analog zu B beide Varianten zu kennzeichen, also "in ein(em) I."

Comment: Da es keine vollständigen Sätze sind steht man ziemlich im Regen mit der Frage, wie man die meisten Sätze durch willkürliche Ergänzungen retten kann. Das ist aber wohl nicht die Frage. Die Frage ist mir unklar..

Comment: @Matthias Die potentielle Doppeldeutigkeit. Ich mein, so wie das da steht ist das ja kein Satz, aber das erste an was ich bei "in einem Ingenieurbüro" denke, ist die Örtlichkeit, wo es stattfindet. Natürlich würde es in einem vollständigen Satz (wahrscheinlich) klar sein. Außerdem ist Genitiv definitiv die schönere Lösung. Wofür gibt es den Fall denn? ;) – Also wohl bemerkt, habe ich die Frage so verstanden, dass OP nicht die Örtlichkeit ausdrücken möchte, sondern um wessen betriebliche Abläufe es sich handelt.

Comment: @MarinosAv Kannst du bitte noch klarstellen, ob es dir um den Ort geht, wo die Einweisung stattfindet oder darum, wessen Abläufe es sind.

Comment: @em1 Nein, es handelt sich um keinen Ort, sondern um die Prozesse für den Betrieb eines Ingenieurbüros

Comment: @MarinosAv Dann ist Genitiv die elegantere Lösung.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Präposition *in* ist eine [Wechselpräposition](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=84), d.h. sie steht mit dem Dativ bei einem Ort (wo?) und mit dem Akkusativ bei einer Richtung (wohin?). *In ein**em** Ingenieurbüro* in dem Beispiel beschreibt den Ort, hier steht also der Dativ (von der Frage, ob eine andere Formulierung besser ist, einmal abgesehen).

Bei *jemanden (Akk) in etwas (Akk) einweisen* ist eine Richtung im übertragenen Sinn gemeint, also steht der Akkusativ. Daher heißt es *in **den** betriebliche**n** Ablauf einweisen* (Singular) oder *in **die** betriebliche**n** Abläufe einweisen* (Plural). Bei Substantivierung (*Einweisung* statt *einweisen*) ändert sich die Konstruktion nicht.

Die korrekten Endungen für den jeweiligen Fall entnimmt man den üblichen Tabellen.

Ich empfehle, gerade bei abstrakten Bedeutungen aber einfach das komplette Verbmuster (also das Verb zusammen mit Präpositionen und Fällen, wie oben angegeben) zu lernen. Man kann sich den Fall durch Überlegen zwar herleiten, aber so geht es einfach schneller.

Die Verbmuster findet man in einem guten Wörterbuch, online z.B. bei [Pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=einweisen&l=deen&in=&lf=de).

Comment: Hm. "In einem Ingenieurbüro" kann auch Ersatz für den wohl besseren Genitiv sein. "Die Abläufe in einem Ingenieurbüro sind anders als jene von anderen Diensleistungsunternehmen". Und mein erstes Verständnis der Frage war, das OP nicht Örtlichkeit ausdrücken wollte. Das muss OP wohl noch klarstellen, aber so oder so sollte es auch in (d)einer Antwort Erwähnung finden...

Comment: Danke!!!!!!!!!! @dirkt

Comment: @Em1: Ich hatte die Frage so verstanden, dass ihm vor allem die grammatischen Regeln für Wechselpräpositionen unklar waren (und sein Kommentar scheint das zu bestätigen). Unter diesem Aspekt ist die Frage der Formulierung (Örtlichkeit vs. Genitiv) meines Erachtens nicht wirklich wichtig.